# Validating an input UTF-8 sequence in a Windows C++ application

Tags: c++, validation, winapi, utf-8

I'd like to validate an input UTF-8 sequence in a Windows application written in C++.

My idea was to simply invoke `MultiByteToWideChar()`, just requesting the destination string length (instead of doing the whole string conversion to UTF-16), and using the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag.
Then, if the function returns 0 (meaning failure) and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION`, that would mean the input UTF-8 sequence contains some invalid data.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Since you are asking for *"better"*, which aspect do you need to improve?

Comment: @IInspectable: If there's no better solution, I'm fine with what I have. Better may mean: faster, or using some _ad hoc_ API for validation (since my understanding is MBTWC was designed with translation in mind, and may have overhead if what we want is just validating UTF-8), things like those.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the internals of MBTWC it would be hard to specify a better approach. It would at least require timing measurements on the use of MBTWC and any alternative approach (if faster is considered better). Implementing your own UTF-8 validator would be a start to allow for comparison. You can find a good reference implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/validating-utf-8-byte-array), have a look at the accepted answer. The Java code would translate to C++ pretty easily and gives you ample opportunity for determining if it's better (for your case) and allow for further improvements if needed.

Comment: *"Without knowing the internals of MBTWC"* - You **do** know some of the internals. For one, `MultiByteToWideChar` will inevitably have to deduce the length of the UTF-16 encoding for each code point. Probably a trivial comparison that returns either 1 or 2, but still something that has to be done in addition to validating the input.